# Shell with unique buffer names

Tags: shell

I use the following function to make a shell buffer, but the unique file name is not taking effect.

```
(defun galaxy-shell ()
  "Make a uniquely named buffer for executing shell commands."
  (interactive)
  (shell)
  (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'rename-uniquely))
```

Comment: The function `shell` takes an *optional* argument for the buffer-name / buffer.  As such, you may wish to consider simply providing that *optional* argument and giving the buffer your own unique name -- e.g., `(shell "*FOO*")`.  Type `C-h f` aka `M-x describe-function` to see the doc-string and arguments a given function contains.

Comment: Also, adding a hook for `shell-mode` _after_ creating the `shell-mode` buffer isn’t going to do anything. You can just add the hook at the top level so that it is always there when shell buffers are created.

Comment: You can use `rename-uniquely`.

Comment: **Please** (1) Don't evolve a question through comments (or even in the question). Post separate questions. *Especially once there is an answer!* (2) Since there are no answers to this question yet, please remove everything in it that's extraneous to what you now want to know - just state your (current) question clearly and succintly. Questions and comments are not meant to be meandering threads that change direction/meaning/purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(defun dilna-foo (&optional x)
  (interactive)
  (shell (generate-new-buffer-name (or x "foo"))))
```